# Create a Julia Datetime from a TimePeriod and StartDate

Tags: julia

I want to convert an Int64 representing the number of microseconds passed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar) into a Julia datetime.

```
julia> time = Dates.Microsecond(6369175082331949400)

julia> Dates.format(time, "yyyymmdd HH:MM:SS.sss")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some of the ideas provided, I came up with:

```
function convert_datetime(time)::DateTime
    num = div(time, 100000)
    remainder = rem(time, 100000)
    time = DateTime(Dates.UTInstant(Millisecond(num))) + Dates.Day(1)
    # time = Dates.epochms2datetime(trade.date_time/100000) + Dates.Year(1) + Dates.Day(1)
    time + Dates.Microsecond(remainder)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a DateTime, just make sure you have your Int64 correctly in milliseconds, and you can use the (undocumented) UTInstant constructor, and then later add back the fractional microseconds (comment: your example number, 6369175082331949400, seems big for recent Gregorian time in microseconds, it may be nanoseconds):

```
julia> using Dates


julia> t = now().instant
Dates.UTInstant{Millisecond}(63694318624788 milliseconds)

julia> dump(t)
Dates.UTInstant{Millisecond}
  periods: Millisecond
    value: Int64 63694318624788

julia> t2 = Dates.UTInstant(Millisecond(63691750823319))
Dates.UTInstant{Millisecond}(63691750823319 milliseconds)

julia> DateTime(t2)
2019-04-24T01:00:23.319

julia> t3 = DateTime(t2)+ Dates.Microsecond(494)
2019-04-24T01:00:23.319
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want using [`Dates.epochms2datetime`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/index.html#Dates.epochms2datetime) and applying an adjustment to it for your case as shown below.

Lets take `datetime_value` as the date we are interested in getting:

```
datetime_value = Dates.DateTime(2019,1,1,0,0,0)
date_start = Dates.DateTime(1,1,1,0,0,0)

date_diff = datetime_value - date_start
```

This gives you a value of `63681897600000 milliseconds` for `date_diff`. Now `Dates.epochms2datetime` considers start of epoch as `0000-01-01T00:00:00`. So we need to add 1 Year and 1 Day to the result after using `Dates.epochms2datetime` to arrive at our datetime value from the milliseconds value:

```
julia> Dates.epochms2datetime(63681897600000) + Dates.Year(1) + Dates.Day(1)
2019-01-01T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, as [Dates.Microsecond merely returns the Int64 value of a Date or Time](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.millisecond). However, you can create the DateTime value from a specific date and then work from there. Subtraction is allowed for DateTime values and [it returns the difference in milliseconds](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Durations/Comparisons-1).

```
using Dates

dateThen = DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
dateNow = now(UTC)
diff = dateNow - dateThen
dump(diff * 1000)
```

Int64 63694261047549000 (or whatever time you run it.)